# SSIS Data Flow Task Violates Unique Constraint But Linked Server Insert Succeeds

Tags: sql-server, ssis, collation, unique-constraint

Ultimately, what I am trying to do is create an SSIS package in the QA environment for another team which truncates the destination tables and inserts from the source tables.  However, on one table, `ITEMMAST`, I am receiving an error due to a unique constraint violation when trying to copy the data using a data flow task.

What is odd is that a `SELECT...INSERT` using a linked server succeeds!  However, I can't use linked servers because this other team wants to be able to specify the environment for the source so I have to parameterize the connection strings.

Here is the definition of the unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ITEMMAST]
  ADD CONSTRAINT [ITESET1]
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
      [ITEM_GROUP] ASC,
      [ITEM] ASC 
  ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90)
  ON [PRIMARY];
```

I've tried dropping the primary key constraint, copying the data, and then recreating the primary key constraint but that also produces an error.

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.ITEMMAST' and the index name 'ITESET1'. The duplicate key value is (SALO ,                                 ).
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 46
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
>   The statement has been terminated.

A developer gave me the following query to run which helped me identify the culprits, one row with 32 spaces in the `ITEM` column and another row with the ASCII character of 0, a null character, in the `ITEM` column.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ITEM) as [Position],
 substring(ITEM,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ITEM),1) as [InvalidCharacter],
 ascii(substring(ITEM,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ITEM),1)) as [ASCIICode]
,*
 FROM Lawson.dbo.ITEMMAST
WHERE ITEM_GROUP = 'SALO'
```

[image]

Here is more information about the QA environment.  These settings match our PROD environment so I'm unable to modify QA to make this work.  I've thought about altering the unique constraint definition and changing the destination database collation.

Source Database Collation: `Latin1_General_BIN`
Collation for the `ITEM` Column in the Source Table: `Latin1_General_BIN`

Destination Database Collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
Collation for the `ITEM` Column in the Destination Table: `Latin1_General_BIN`

I checked that the codepage for the `Latin1_General_BIN` collation is 1252 which matches the codepage for the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation.

Does anyone have any suggestions for other things that I can try?  I'm new to SSIS so there might be a setting that I did not set correctly.

**[UPDATE #1]**

Screen shot showing the result of the following query from the source table.

```
SELECT TOP 2
 CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), [ITEM])
,ITEM COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [ITEM_Collated]
,*
FROM PROD.dbo.ITEMMAST
WHERE ITEM_GROUP = 'SALO'
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the operation via SSIS is converting the collation to the destination database's default collation, which isn't a binary collation, and so it is stripping off the trailing blanks and `CHAR(0)` before inserting the values, hence the duplicate. This is also why the Linked Server works: it maintains the collation since it knows of the destination column's collation. I don't work with SSIS (anymore, thankfully ;) so I am not entirely sure how to proceed. Do you have any options for specifying the collation of the operation / query / etc? Can you specify a property for 1 column?

Comment: I backed up and restored the destination database under a different name and just tried to change the collation of the destination database to `Latin1_General_BIN` but the data flow task still failed.

I also tried changing the OLE DB Source to use a SQL command as the Data access mode instead of the name of a table or view and explicitly specifying the collation for the `ITEM` column but that didn't work either.


`SELECT
ITEM_GROUP COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS ITEM_GROUP,ITEM COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS ITEM
...
FROM ITEMMAST`

Comment: Maybe try explicitly casting the field in a derived column? Or how about allowing the NULL values to flow through (this might affect all the other columns negatively though)?

Comment: Casting as a derived column--like this? `CAST(ITEM AS CHAR(32)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS ITEM`

I tried making the `ITEM` column nullable but then it can't be used as part of the unique constraint definition.

Comment: AABCDS: When replying to someone, you need to specify their `@` name so that they get notified of the message, unless they are the one who posted the question or answer being commented on (in which case they always get notified). So I will use @JacobH to notify that person of your response above. (FYI: you can only use one `@` reference in a comment!)

Comment: @AABCDS Adding the `COLLATE` to the `SELECT` likely does nothing. The issue has something to do with how SSIS handles the collation. Isn't there a way to edit properties of each incoming, or outgoing column? Also, are you sure that you are connecting directly to the destination DB? (most likely yes, but might need to verify). Can you have SSIS dump the data in, without any PK or Unique constraint/index, and then see what got inserted? I think we need to ignore the query the developer gave you and find what SQL Server considers to be the issue. So ... (continuted)

Comment: @AABCDS find duplicate rows in the destination table. Then, go to the source table and find any rows that would match the duplicate values. You will have to force the collation in the query on the source table to be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. And when viewing those rows, add another column in the select list for `CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), [ITEM])` so that we can see what is truly there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the derived column task, as part of your data flow. If I am understanding from your example, the `0` is being converted to an empty string, and so is the `NULL`--which causes the violation of the constraint--correct?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky So I dropped the unique primary key constraint on the destination table and used the SSIS data flow task to populate the destination table.  Afterwards, I used the following query and there were no duplicates.

`SELECT ITEM_GROUP
   ,ITEM
   ,COUNT(*)
FROM Lawson.dbo.ITEMMAST
GROUP BY ITEM_GROUP
  ,ITEM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

I've added a screen shot of `CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), [ITEM])` to my original post above.  I'm still looking into your other suggestion for SSIS settings.

Comment: @AABCDS Are 100% of the rows there? That is querying the destination table?  If so, can you create the PK? If not, are you sure that the collation on _both_ destination columns is the `BIN` collation? For the query against the source, you don't need the `COLLATE` there. It doesn't do anything. You only need the `COLLATE` if doing the `GROUP BY` such that it will simulate what might be causing this issue. Also, I just remembered something. For the source query in SSIS, trying using `CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), [ITEM])` instead of `[ITEM] COLLATE...`. Not sure if SSIS will let you, but worth trying.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Yes, 100% of the rows were transferred to the destination table.  I cannot create the PK; I get the error listed above.  Yes, the collation on the `ITEM_GROUP` and `ITEM` columns in the destination table are `Latin1_General_BIN`.  I went through these steps again just to make sure.  I will try that source query.

Comment: @JacobH I added a Derived Column task between the OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination inside of the data flow task.  I used this as the conversion `(DT_STR, 32, 1252) SUBSTRING([ITEM],1, 32)` which did not work.  The datatype of the `ITEM` column is CHAR(32).  The problem is that one row has the ASCII character zero [NUL character] and the other row has 32 spaces.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Using `CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), [ITEM])` did not work.  The data flow task failed with a `data would be truncated` error.  Also, I'm not setting any place inside of the OLE DB Source or OLE DB Destination to set the properties of the output or input columns.  I'm using VIsual Studio 2008 which is compatible with our PROD environment.

Comment: I talked to another DBA at work and he suggested using a source query to filter that top row out.  It's just QA and I doubt the application uses that first row anyway.

Comment: @AABCDS I only picked 500 because I didn't know the size of the column. Try using `CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), [ITEM])` instead. Also, it is odd that a query to find duplicates returns no rows, yet attempting to create the PK on those same two columns errors with a uniqueness violation. How about doing that same query that you used on the source (with the `CONVERT(VARBINARY(..` ) on the destination to see if those rows show up the same there.

Comment: If we can find the exact issue that would be best since if a work-around works now, there is no telling that it will continue to do so. There is something simple being overlooked here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83291/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-aabcds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the O.P. check for duplicates in the destination table. The following query was used:

```
SELECT ITEM_GROUP, ITEM, COUNT(*)
FROM Lawson.dbo.ITEMMAST
GROUP BY ITEM_GROUP, ITEM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The result was:

> 0x2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020

The row starting with 7 "nul" characters (i.e. `CHAR(0)` or `0x00`, see image #2 in the question) was replaced with a row of all spaces.

The problem is that the first character is `0x00`, which is the null terminator for strings. Pulling that value into SSIS (i.e. .NET) probably viewed it as a simple empty string. And inserting an empty string into a `CHAR()` column (i.e. a blank-padded datatype) will naturally leave you with all spaces. Hence your duplicate row.

At this point, I would say that it's simply bad data, unless you feel a need to preserve an invalid string (no string should ever have anything after a `0x00`, nor should it really even have the `0x00`, but if it does, it would be the last character).

So, you can correct that row at the source, but it can't be an empty string since that would get the same PK violation that you are running into now. Is there a default dummy value?

Or, if that row is truly invalid / not used, then I would remove it, OR maybe find out how that row got there in the first place. Did someone manually enter it, did the app create it? Was it a botched import? You might take this opportunity to add a `CHECK` constraint to ensure that no row has the 0x00 character in it in the future (this would help identify the culprit in the future). Then delete the row from QA and move on... :)

I suppose you can always try to exclude that row if need be, but it would be best to prevent it from ever existing. It will never appear correctly when selected. And there might be other negative impacts downstream in the future. How much time have you (and I ;) spent on finding / fixing this? Do you really want to do it again, or have someone else hunt this down? If that row could never show up in prod, then it should be removed from QA.